# Linq Select if column value in another linq query

Tags: linq

So I want to select all rows that have contact_id that is in another linq query.

```
var test1 = this.DB.Links.Where(l => l.INSTANCE_ID == this.InstanceId);
var test2 = this.DB.Links.Select (l => test1.Contains(l.CONTACT_ID)));
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

EDIT:  Try to materialize it first with `ToList()`, get this error: `Argument 1:  Cannot convert from long?  to Anonomous type long? CONTACT_ID`.

Comment: Are you using Linq To SQL or Linq to Entities ? And what is not working for you ?

Comment: Linq to SQL.  It say the type argument cannot be inffered from usage on "Contains".

Comment: Can you add some more detail about the data type and what you expect the results to be?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it was an error from another part of the program, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `Select` and `ToList` to materialize a collection of `CONTACT_ID`s in the first query. Also, the second query needs to have `Where` instead of `Select`:

```
var test1 = this.DB.Links
    .Where(l => l.INSTANCE_ID == this.InstanceId)
    .Select(l => l.CONTACT_ID)
    .ToList();
var test2 = this.DB.Links.Where(l => test1.Contains(l.CONTACT_ID)));
```

Comment: Given it is an `ID` (thus probably something like an `int` or `string`, perhaps a `HashSet<T>` is more appropriate.

Comment: @CommuSoft Are you talking about the `ToList`? It won't really matter, since the whole collection needs to be iterated and injected into the SQL string. Whether you use a `HashSet` or a `List` or whatever is immaterial.

Comment: inserting into the hashset will indeed have approximately the same time complexity (*O(n log n)*), but then you have to query, for each item in `this.DB.Links` this collection. Given the collection has length *n* and the result of `test1` has *k* elements, the time complexity of using the `.ToList` approach is *O(n+k log k+n k)* whereas for a `HashSet` we expect constant time lookups thus resulting in *O(n+k log k+n)=O(n+k log k)*

Comment: @CommuSoft The query isn't occurring literally against the `List`. The elements of the list are taken and interpolated into an SQL string, which is then evaluated by the SQL server. At that point it doesn't matter at all whether the values in the `IN` clause in the SQL string came from a List or a HashSet or whatever else. There's no performance difference.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Some LINQ providers will perform better if you don't do the ToList.  It will try and create a single query from both and execute it once rather than two independent queries.  Some LINQ providers will error without it.  I believe LINQ to SQL is the later type, while later versions of LINQ over EF is the former, just an FYI.

Comment: @RobertMcKee That's interesting. From my (admittedly fuzzy) memory I recall EF choking and spewing out some horrific query when I tried doing a `Contains` against a nested query. Maybe things have improved now.